# Происхождение слова "махина"

Tags: этимология

О чем-то огромном говорят "махина". Но это слово, честно говоря, всегда оставалось для меня загадкой. Каково его происхождение, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это древнерусское заимствование из латинского языка, который данное слово позаимствовал с греческого. Что интересно, слово "машина" имеет те же корни, но пришло к нам намного позднее и уже через западноевропейские языки.

Answer (score 2):

В санскрите есть слово "маха", что означает - "великий". Слово "махина" воспринимается нами, как нечто огромное, великое. Санскрит - старейший язык на земле, многие слова пришли к нам оттуда: гхоре - ужасно(сравните - горе), вякана -речь(сравните -вяканье), будх - будить, агни - огонь, набха - небо и т.д. До прихода христианства на Руси существовали Веды - древнейшие священые тексты. Как они попали к славянам, - это вопрос неизученный, но то, что они читались и почитались нашими предками, - факт бесспорный. Само существование в русском языке огромного количества слов, схожих с санскритом, косвенно подтверждает это.

Comment: Дело обстоит точно наоборот: Веды попали от славян к индийцам. Известный индийский санскритолог Тилак Бал даже написал книгу "Арктическая Родина в Ведах".